# Create a stimestamp in the form of hh:mm:ss:mss with python

Tags: python

I'd like to convert floats / decimals to a timestamp in the form of hh:mm:ss:mss, where mss are milliseconds.

I managed to get a hh:mm:ss timestamp already. But I cannot figure out how to extend the below function.

```
def format_seconds_to_hhmmssms(seconds):
    hours = seconds // (60*60)
    seconds %= (60*60)
    minutes = seconds // 60
    seconds %= 60
    milliseconds %= seconds // 1000
    return "%02i:%02i:%02i:%03i" % (hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)
```

Comment: Ahm, if your granularity is seconds, how are you supposed to get anything other then 0 for the milliseconds in your time stamp? Why not just append the string `":000"`?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something. If you're passing in seconds, you're always going to have an absolute 0 for milliseconds. Or are you planning on passing in a decimal, such as 400.5 (seconds)?

Comment: could you not do `milliseconds = (seconds%1)*1000`?

Comment: disflux. you are correct. I am passing in a float/decimal. corrected my question

Comment: M.T. your suggestion works. Make an answer out of it, so I can accept it. Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming seconds is a float/decimal number:

```
milliseconds = (seconds%1)*1000
```

This will get the remainder of dividing by one (ie. the value after the comma) which can then be multiplied by 1000 to get the equivalent number in milliseconds.

Alternatively one could subtract the truncated value:

```
milliseconds = (seconds-int(seconds))*1000
```